# How to set a default attribute on Rails select form helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to override Rails' `select` method with a custom form helper, so that all select boxes get a `disabled` attribute by default:

```
class LabelFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  def select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
    html_options.reverse_merge! :disabled => true
    super(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
  end

end
```

The problem is that the code is not working and that it doesn't change anything in the way the select boxes are rendered. It doesn't throw an error either.

This would be the view code that I use to call the function:

```
<%= f.select(:person_id, current_user.person_names, {:prompt => 'Please select...'}) %>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Can you ensure that your method is the one getting called? Adding a `raise` in your method and seeing it blow up should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it does get called. I just checked it.

Comment: Was this ever solved?  I'm needing to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try it maybe with

```
<%= f.select(:person_id, current_user.person_names, {}, {:prompt => 'Please select...'}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't change anything unfortunately :-(